# How can I extract words from a text file in R?

Tags: r

I have the following problem: I have a CSV file with, among other things, two columns "Primeword" and "Answer", something like this:

| Primeword | Answer |
| --- | --- |
| Sadness | 2 |
| Anger | 1 |

"Answer" indicates which of two words was remembered. **Where "1 = Recogword1" and "2 = Recogword2"**. 
Just for comprehension: This is data from an experiment in which participants first saw a primeword, e.g. sadness, and then were asked to indicate which of two recogwords they saw previously. *Among the two recogwords was the primeword from the "Primeword" column and another word e.g. Funding*. However, from the CSV file I can no longer see in which order the words were presented. But this information is in a log-file (textfile), which looks like this:

> 510.021   EXP ekel: autoDraw = null 
> 510.021   EXP wut: autoDraw = null 
> 510.021   EXP **recogwort1_2:** **text = Funding** 
> 510.021   EXP **recogwort2_2:** **text = Sadness** 
> 510.021   EXP instruktion_5: autoDraw = true 
> 510.021   EXP recogslider_2: autoDraw = true 
> 484.40200000000004    EXP ekel: autoDraw = null 
> 484.40200000000004    EXP wut: autoDraw = null 
> 484.40200000000004    EXP **recogwort1_2: text** = **Nachweis** 
> 484.40200000000004    EXP **recogwort2_2: text** = **Anger** 
> 484.40200000000004    EXP instruktion_5: autoDraw = true 
> 484.40200000000004    EXP recogslider_2: autoDraw = true

This means: In Trial 1 the word Sadness was displayed. Then the participant was asked to make a decision between the words Funding (recogwort1_2) and Sadness (recogwort2_2). Because his answer was "2", he was correct in this trial (Primeword == recogwort). Finally, in Trial 2, the word Anger was displayed, and so on....

Because we are dealing with a total of 100 CSV files and log files, I am looking for a way in R that produces the following output:

| Primeword | Answer |
| --- | --- |
| Sadness | TRUE |
| Anger | FALSE |

So "Answer" should take the value "TRUE" if Primeword == Answer or in other words if Primeword == Recogwort.
Would greatly appreciate any help! Unfortunately, I am an R beginner.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with your intended solution for others to help you. Sharing what you have done so far will also help a lot.